# Программно назначить обработчик события компонента формы

Tags: c++, radstudio

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, как в Rad Studio c++ Builder программно назначить обработчик события вызова метода компонента формы и его же отключить. Что-то вроде:

```
TTrackBar MyTrbr;
MyTrbr->OnChange += MyMethod;

// Какие-то действия

MyTrbr->OnChange -= MyMethod;
```

Comment: Вам нужно **назначить** или **добавить** еще один обработчик к существующему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено:

```
MyTrbr->OnChange = MyMethod;

// Какие-то действия

MyTrbr->OnChange = NULL;
```